# Getting Errors from Entity Framework Core for a List contains another List

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, blazor-server-side

I have a List of SkillIDs, and I want to include the records from database that have that list in their skills:

```
List<int> skillIDs = skills.Where(s => s.Checked == true)?.Select(s => s.Id)?.ToList<int>() ?? new List<int>();
if (skillIDs.Count() > 0)
{
    jobSeekers = jobSeekers.Where(js => js.ProfileJobs
         .Where(pj => skillIDs.All(s => pj.ProfileJobSkills.Select(pjs => pjs.SkillId).Contains(s))).Any());
         //.Where(pj => pj.ProfileJobSkills.Select(pjs => pjs.SkillId).Intersect(skillIDs).Count() == skillIDs.Count()).Any());
}
```

I either Get "Bug or Limitation" Error from Entity Framework core for the intersect and except or I get "Can't translate and use client evaluation" Error from EF Core, Ofcourse I don't want to use client evaluation since data is large, What do I do?

**For the not commented code I get:**

selector: (p2) => p2.SkillId), \r\n            item: s)))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync().

**and For the commented code I get:**

{"Processing of the LINQ expression 'Intersect(\r\n ...  by 'NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor' failed. This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in EF Core.

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Also check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query for SQL related questions. And add the full error message you get to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
List<int> skillIDs = skills.Where(s => s.Checked == true)
     .Select(s => s.Id)
     .ToList<int>() ?? new List<int>();

if (skillIDs.Count() > 0)
{
    jobSeekers = jobSeekers
      .Where(js => 
         js.ProfileJobs != null && 
         js.ProfileJobs.Any(pj => 
              pj.ProfileJobSkills != null &&
              pj.ProfileJobSkills.Any(pjs => 
                   skillIds.Contains(pjs.SkillId))
     ); 
 }
```

Because you have multiple layers in your table relationships, you can't obtain the cleanest query.  Something like this should work though.